# ViewPager for Screen Slides without swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager, screen, slide

I want to use a Screen slide but without swipe. I see this example: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html , only i want slide pages with the top menu and not with the swipe.
How I can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have implemented it.  In this example I have a ViewPager with 3 items in the adapter and it swipes to the next item every 3 seconds.  After it reaches the third item it goes back to the first position.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    int page = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity22);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    }

    private void testing() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (page == 3) {
                    page = 0;
                }
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(page++);
                testing();
            }
        }, 3000); // 3 seconds
    }
}
```

**Disable Swipe**

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Swipe Views with Tabs". Here's how:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html